# javascript code execute on button click but not on enter key presses

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am searching location onclick on button. result is getting on onclick button. but same code i have put in submit function but here searching is not working.

on button click code.(this is working)

```
    $("#gobuttton").click(function() {
        $("#gmaplatlon").validate({
            rules:{"latitude":{number:true}, "longitude":{number:true}, "zoom":{digits:true,min:0}},
            errorPlacement:errorMessages
        });
        $("#address").change(function(){
            geocoder.geocode({"address": $(this).attr("value")}, function(results, status) { if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { map.setZoom(16); map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location); } else { alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status); } });
        });
});
```

press enter button code(same but not working)

```
     $('#frm').keypress(function(e) {
     var code = e.keyCode;
     if(code === 13){
         e.preventDefault();
         alert(code);
         $("#gmaplatlon").validate({rules:{"latitude":{number:true}, "longitude":{number:true}, "zoom":{digits:true,min:0}}, errorPlacement:errorMessages});
         $("#address").change(function(){ geocoder.geocode({"address": $(this).attr("value")}, function(results, status) { if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { map.setZoom(16); map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location); } else { alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status); } }); });
       }
});
```

my functionality is - enter address in textbox and press enter key then it should be searching on google map, this is executed on button click but not when enter key is pressed.

HTML code is as follows

```
<form method="post" name="frm" id="frm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo site_url('home/sendmapdata');?>"> 
 <input name="address" type="text" id="address" border: solid 1px; " size="60" value="Search from address" onClick="this.value=''"> 
<input type="button" id="gobuttton" value="go"> 
<div id="map_canvas" style="height: 480px; width:665px; " ></div> 
<input type="hidden" name="gmaplatlon" value="true"> 
<p align="center">
<input type="submit" name="okbutton" value="OK" >
</p>
</form>
```

Comment: can you share your html code too ?

Comment: remove e.preventDefault()

Comment: <form method="post" name="frm" id="frm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo site_url('home/sendmapdata');?>">    <input name="address" type="text" id="address" 
                         border: solid 1px;  " size="60" value="Search from address" onClick="this.value=''">
                        <input type="button" id="gobuttton" value="go">     <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 480px; width:665px;  " ></div> <input type="hidden" name="gmaplatlon" value="true">    <p align="center"><input type="submit" name="okbutton" value="OK" ></p></form>

Comment: if i remove e.prevntDefault() then its working but for submited also. i need that after enter its execute searching not form submite.

Answer (score 2):

Tyr this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#address').keypress(function(e) {
         var code = e.keyCode;
         if(code === 13){
             //e.preventDefault();
             alert(code);
             $("#gmaplatlon").validate({rules:{"latitude":{number:true}, "longitude":{number:true}, "zoom":{digits:true,min:0}}, errorPlacement:errorMessages});
             $("#address").change(function(){ geocoder.geocode({"address": $(this).attr("value")}, function(results, status) { if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { map.setZoom(16); map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location); } else { alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status); } }); });
         }
         return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: if i remove e.preventDefault() then its working but form is submited. i need only searching execute not  submit form.

Comment: Adding a line in code `return false` can solve your problem. I changed my answer, check it.

Comment: any other idea for preventing form submition ?

Comment: In you `form element` add `onsubmit="return false;"`, Also if you have any work to do `on submit` then you can call it from `onclick` of `submit button`.

Comment: on submit click i am executing form submition. so i need map searching on enter key press.

Comment: Enter `automatically submits` the `form`. So you can do it on `downarrow' or 'any other key press event`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25510/discussion-between-rohan-kumar-and-user2122323)

Answer (score 1):

Try this change `$('#frm').keypress(function(e)` to `$('#address').keypress(function(e)`

UPDATE:

I think your issue is validate which is preventing from calling the map function, add this `$('#frm').valid()` inside your keypress function

Answer (score 0):

You should try to give keypress event to `#address` instead of `#frm`:

```
$('#frm').on('keypress', '#address', function(e) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `e.preventDefault();` after Google map work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#address').keypress(function(e) {
         var code = e.keyCode;
         if(code === 13){
             //e.preventDefault();
             alert(code);
             $("#gmaplatlon").validate({rules:{"latitude":{number:true}, "longitude":{number:true}, "zoom":{digits:true,min:0}}, errorPlacement:errorMessages});
             $("#address").change(function(){ geocoder.geocode({"address": $(this).attr("value")}, function(results, status) { if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { map.setZoom(16); map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location); } else { alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status); } }); });
         }
         e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: at a time any 1 functionality is executing. if prevented form submit then map is not working And if map searching then for submit is not working. but i want searching map as well as prevent form submition.